# Find the result of tic-tac-toe in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to write an function which displays who is the winner in the game of tic tac toe.
If X is the winner it returns `X`, If O is the winner it returns `O` and for a draw, it returns boolean `None`
What I tried works for some cases and fails for test cases given below Please help .

```
def check_winner(tuples):
    for row in range(0, len(tuples)):
        print(tuples[row])
        for col in range(0,3):

            #check for row win
            if tuples[row][0] == tuples[row][1] == tuples[row][2]:
                print("1 ")
                # return tuples[row][0];
            #check for col win
            if tuples[0][col] == tuples[1][col] == tuples[2][col]:
                print("2")
                return tuples[row][0];
            # For diagonal
            if tuples[0][0] == tuples[1][1] == tuples[2][2]:
                return tuples[0][0]
            if tuples[0][2] == tuples[1][1] == tuples[2][0]:
                return tuples[2][0]
```

For test cases below

```
# O wins
test1 = (('X', 'O', 'O'),
        (None, 'O', 'X'),
        ('X', 'O', 'X'))
# X Wins
test2 = (('X', 'X', 'O'),
        (("O", 'X', 'O'),
        ('O', 'X', 'X'))
```

Calling function

```
print(check_winner(test1))
print(check_winner(test2))
```

should return O and X respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return `return tuples[row][0];` in the second if statement. It should be something like `tuples[0][col]` if you want to return the value of the winner.

You don't need nested for loops to check for rows and columns. There are just 3 of each that you should check.

Try this instead:

```
def check_winner(tuples):
    for line in range(3):
            #check for row win
            if tuples[line][0] == tuples[line][1] == tuples[line][2]:
                print("1 ")
                return tuples[line][0];
            #check for col win
            if tuples[0][line] == tuples[1][line] == tuples[2][line]:
                print("2")
                return tuples[0][line];
    # For diagonal
    if tuples[0][0] == tuples[1][1] == tuples[2][2]:
        return tuples[0][0]
    if tuples[0][2] == tuples[1][1] == tuples[2][0]:
        return tuples[2][0]
```

Comment: `test3 = ((None, 'X', 'O'),
         ('X', 'O', 'X'),
         ('O', 'O', 'X'))`
this fails and returns O instead of None

Comment: @Firearmz It is printing the character used by the winner and It works on this test too

Comment: for test 3 no one should be the winner but your code returns O

Comment: @Firearmz Looking at the test, O is winning on the diagonal

Comment: Sorry, my bad! guess the auto grader for my assignment is broken.Thanks for the help :)